# Help with displaying content from MySQL db by id

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to put together my first dynamic site using PHP and MySQL - nube central!

I'm going great guns on building the database and inserting data.  Now I'd like to display the content of each row in a php/html template.

I've created a php file that lists every row with a link to a story.php file:

```
<a href="story.php?id=<? echo $row->id; 
?>"><?

echo $row->Name; ?></a>
```

But when I want to build story.php file I get an error when using:

```
$query = "SELECT Name, Address FROM garden WHERE id ='$id'";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query. " .

mysql_error());
```

If I hard code WHERE id ='1'" for example, it displays that row fine, but using '$id' returns nothing.

How can I get it to return the data in the row based on the id in the link ie:

```
http://localhost:8888/test/tiebel/story.php?id=1
```

Comment: Lets "destringify" your id value. If the datatype for id is an integer in the database you don't need the single quotes around the variable.

Comment: Thanks a million @cyberkiwi - I did that and I get "Error in query: SELECT Name, Address FROM Tiebel_Gardens_Homes WHERE id = . You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1" :(

Answer (score 0):

I guess ID is numeric, so drop the quotes

```
$query = "SELECT Name, Address FROM garden WHERE id =$id";
```

---

> "Error in query: SELECT Name, Address FROM Tiebel_Gardens_Homes WHERE id = .

For this one, you need to

1. get the ID from the GET/POST parameters
2. gracefully handle where the ID is not provided

So I would do this

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
if (!is_numeric($id)) { $id = 0; }
$query = "SELECT Name, Address FROM garden WHERE id =$id";
```

Comment: Thanks cyberkiwi - I changed it to

Answer (score 0):

You may be trying to take advantage of '[register_globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php)', not a good move. Also, if that was in place, I could trash a database with: "http://localhost:8888/test/tiebel/story.php?id=1; drop table garden".

The value 'id' is available, as $_GET['id'], but I would further do something like this:

```
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? int($_GET['id']) : 0;
if ($id == 0) {
   echo "problem with id";
   exit;
}
```

This makes sure that the variable is 
  a) actually set in the first place and
  b) is a number.

If anything that is not a number (or at least, does not start with a number) is appended to the URL, it will be converted to an integer, fail and show up as 0, which gets checked.

As the other answer says, if it is a simple number, you don't need quotes around it, but that also requires some security, else it could be '....?id=id' which ends up as `SELECT Name, Address FROM garden WHERE id=id` (selecting all rows).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you're asking:

When id=## in your URL, you're setting a $_GET value.  Try:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

before your query.

Comment: Thanks @Trevor - that nailed it!!  Thanks @Alister - I tried trashing the DB as you point out and it failed so guess I'm OK.  This is a project to get me into PHP/MySQL - loads of security stuff yet to learn but thanks for point that out.  James